# inotifytools_next_event(0) is blocking

Tags: c, linux, inotify

I'm trying to work with inotify.  For some reason inotifytools_next_event is blocking forever, despite putting a 0 in the timeout field. Did I miss something?

```
inotifytools_initialize();
inotifytools_watch_recursively(".", IN_CLOSE_WRITE|IN_DELETE|IN_MODIFY);
inotifytools_next_event(0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there was an official bug [report](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/44036?project=5).

Wich basically has been fixed by

```
Closed by  Sergej Pupykin (sergej)

Wednesday, 04 March 2015, 12:31 GMT

Reason for closing:  Fixed
```

Try to update the `inotify-tools` with recent source changes.